# Get object from variable value?

Tags: javascript

This seems so simple...

I have an object

```
var VR03 = {
    name: "Eternal Growth Ring",
    price: "2500"
}
```

I have a function, where I assign a variable a string

```
function myFunction(){
    js_type = jQuery('#type').val();
    console.log(js_type); //returns "VR03"
}
```

How can I return `VR03.name` by only using `js_type`?

```
function myFunction(){
    jQuery('h1').text(?);
}
```

I have tried `String(js_type).name` but this results in the same as  `js_type.name`

Comment: You have several objects, properties, functions etc.  Okay, where's the code?

Comment: Don't put your code in the comments.  Insert the **minimal, verifiable code** inside the question itself.

Comment: *"I assign a variable a string"* - No you don't. The code you show assigns a reference to the object.

Comment: sorry, i fixed the missing quotation marks. @nnnnnn

Comment: Why do you need to reference VR03 using its name as a string? If you just set `js_type = VR03` in `myFunction`, then `js_type.name` will work as expected.

Comment: if you remove those quotation marks then you can access the name using `js_type.name`.

Comment: I don't even understand what you are asking.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Because I am getting the value elsewhere, as a string, from a variable in the URL for example

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to dynamically look up an object based on a string is to use another object as a lookup table:

```
var types = {
    "VR03": {
        name: "Eternal Growth Ring",
        price: "2500"
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var js_type = jQuery('#type').val();
    var type = types[js_type];
    if (type)
        jQuery('h1').text(type.name);
    else
        // Type not found.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In browser, you can try

```
window[js_type].name
```

since your VR03 is a global variable.
But it is just a very bad idea to set it as a global variable.